# Installing HP Printer on Crouton, HPLIP says CUPS is missing

Tags: software-installation, printing, hp, hplip

I'm trying to get my HP Deskjet 3000 hooked up through crouton on my Toshiba Chromebook. I followed the instructions for installation from http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html and I eventually ran into this:

```
DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION
----------------------------------
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: A required dependency 'cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)' is still missing.


RUNNING POST-PACKAGE COMMANDS
-----------------------------
OK


RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES
------------------------
error: A required dependency 'cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.
```

But then when I run:

```
sudo apt-get install cups
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
cups is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libglade2-0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(precise)alan@localhost:~$
```

I'm kind of lost at this point. How do I get CUPS installed to where hplip recognizes it, and completes the installation?

Answer (score 2):

To start the service execute:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cups start
```

it worked for me

Comment: This also worked for me -- not sure why the answer is downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I resolved it just by running the Cups service:

```
service cups start
```

It looks that the HP install script is actually checking if the service is started to infer if the package is installed.

Answer (score 0):

**16.04 + systemd**

```
sudo systemctl start cups
sudo systemctl start cups-browsed
```